# codecept: command not found

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2, codeception

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu and after installing Yii2 etc I can't seem to be able to run codecept anymore.

I'm using Yii2. I required the latest codecept version in composer.json which is working fine. But I can't seem to find a way to get codeception running again.

I've been looking through all the guides but none of them have anything other then just to composer require or add it to the composer.json. I do have noticed when I wanted to add codecept to my $PATH that I don't have a codecept file in root/vendor/bin/, where I think the $PATH entry should point to.

I have no idea where to go from here. Did I miss some step somewhere maybe?
Just to sum things up:

- codeception (yiisoft/yii2-codeception) is installed.
- root/vendor/bin/ does not contain anything that points to codeception.
- command: codecept run unit returns: codecept: Command not found
- command: (./)vendor/bin/codecept return: "path": no such file or directory.

Comment: Do you have `"config": { "bin-dir": "bin"}` set in your composer.json file, because that's the path that codeception uses to install its executable phar file, if not, add it to the composer.json file, and update composer, you should now be able to run `bin/codecept run unit`. Alternatively, the third command you've tried should've been `./codecept run unit`, not `codecept run unit`, maybe give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've already installed codeception by adding it to my composer.json. I've tried    ./codecept run unit doesn't work either. That is how I run ./yii commands, but on my pre-installed system that wasn't necassary.

Answer (score 12):

**`codecept: command not found` on Ubuntu then you should follow these steps:**

```
sudo composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.1.*" "codeception/specify=*" "codeception/verify=*"
```

and then run this command:

```
sudo ln -s ~/.composer/vendor/bin/codecept    /usr/local/bin/codecept
```

So `codecept build` and `codecept run` will work.

---

**If you are using Windows then run this command:**

```
composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.1.*" "codeception/specify=*" "codeception/verify=*"
```

Add this line into your path:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add composer global packages binaries to your PATH.

For local development I'm using Vagrant, here is example for it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Comment: Vagrant seems like an interesting option! Will look into that, since that would prevent ever having this problem again. Though composer is in my path already, since I can call that one globally.

Comment: @Wijnand I actually mean composer global packages binaries.

Answer (score -1):

If you have some like this error:

```
$ php ./vendor/bin/codecept run
Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/codecept
```

Just run:

```
$ rm composer.lock 
$ composer update
```

Comment: Using composer update will update the packages which might be not compatible with your code, So you may face issues. Haven't tested whether this works or not but can try with rm composer.lock and then composer install instead of composer update