# codecept: command not found in PhpStorm + Babun

Tags: environment-variables, phpstorm, codeception, babun

I´m trying to use [Codeception for WordPress](https://codeception.com/for/wordpress).

**Environment**

- OS : Windows 10
- IDE : PhpStorm
- Terminal (in PhpStorm) : Babun

I managed with `composer` to build the project `wp-browser` but when I try to run a command with the key word `codecept`, I got this error :

> bash: codecept: command not found

I checked my PhpStorm configuration in `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks` and I can see :

```
Path to codeception executable : E:\path\my-test-project\vendor\codeception\codeception
```

I had in PATH for all users `E:\path\my-test-project\vendor\codeception\codeception` after following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413403/codecept-command-not-found), without success.

When I test the command `codecept` in Babun outside the PHPStorm Terminal, that works, so it seems to be a PhpStorm problem.

What could be the thing I forgot ?

Comment: Correct path is `E:\path\my-test-project\vendor\codeception\codeception\`

Comment: Yes, it war an error inside the question. It´s what it was generated by composer so the problem is not that. I will modify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again and now it works.
I´m not sure the reason why but it could be because on PHPStorm I clicked (to resolve an other problem ) on

> `File > Invalidated Caches / Restart...`.